# How can I detect whether or not a call to an external JavaScript file has occurred?

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to create a sandbox where I can check if a tracking pixel has successfully executed or not.

Essentially, a successful pixel fire creates a request for an external JavaScript file. When this script runs correctly it creates this:

```
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="a.adroll.com/j/roundtrip.js"></script>
```

How do I go about detecting that? Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "a call to an external javascript file has occurred"?  What is that?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm sure it could be described in a much better way. Essentially, a successful pixel fire creates a request for an external javascript file. When this script runs correctly it creates this: '<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="http://a.adroll.com/j/roundtrip.js"></script>'. How do I go about detecting that?

Comment: I provded an answer that addresses some of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to detect whether a tracking pixel has been added to your page and successfully loaded, you can find it in the DOM and check if the image has completed loading with the `.complete` property.

If you're trying to detect whether some external javascript has been called, you can't do that directly unless the code leaves some state around that you can interrogate indicating it's been called or perhaps hacking the code in question before it's called to replace it with your own function that can log it being called and then call the original function.

Without more details about your problem (the actual code and HTML), we can't offer more specifics.

---

I see you added a little more info in a comment.  If you want to know if a specific script has been loaded, then you can look at that script and see what global symbols it defines and test for the existence of one of those global symbols.  If they are not defined, then the script has not been loaded yet.  If they are defined, then it has.

For example, if the script (roundtrip.js) defines a global function named `__adroll` (which it looks like that script does), you can test for its existence with:

```
if (window.__adroll) {
    // symbol __adroll is defined
}
```

---

To test for the existence of this variable in an iframe on the same domain as your host page, you would have to get the window object for that iframe.  Using `id="iframe"` from your code example, you could do that like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_");
var iframWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
if (iframeWin && iframeWin.__adroll) {
    // symbol __adroll is defined in the iframe
} else {
    // symbol __adroll is either not defined in the iframe or
    // the iframe window is not accessible for cross-domain security reasons
}
```

Comment: I looked at the roundtrip.js script you included and it looks like you can test to see if it's loaded by looking for the `__adroll` symbol as I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: I seem to be getting false positives when I attempt to execute this. I am inputting the code shown in the following [link] (http://cl.ly/image/3b2L2X3h2K3w) Any idea what could be causing the false positive?

Comment: @VictorTorres - your screen shot shows different code.  I don't know what you're attempting to do with that code (and it doesn't make any sense to me), but it's not the code I suggested.

Comment: The reason for the different code is that I am trying to detect the __adroll in an iframe that lives on the same page with the ID of 'iframe_'. You can see the whole project here at http://www.fundifi.com/victor/pixel_sandbox/sandbox.html

Comment: @VictorTorres - this is why you should always describe the whole problem in your question.  Checking for the var in an iframe is a more complicated problem because it's a separate javascript execution context.  I've added to the end of my answer how you can do that.

Comment: This is awesome, just one question. Why iframeWin && iframeWin.__adroll?

Comment: @VictorTorres - it protects your code if the `iframeWin` is null or undefined for some reason, so it goes to the `else` branch without throwing an error.